# How to concatenate multiple if statement results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on a simple system that will produce the name of a task that is coming up within five days of `TODAY()`'s date. I was successful in getting one single case to populate. However, let's say there are two upcoming assignments due both within a five-day period, I am having trouble trying to get both results to show.

Here is my formula so far:

`=IF(AND($W12-TODAY()>=-5,$Y12<>"Yes"),"Invite 1",IF(AND($Z12-TODAY()>=-5,$AB12<>"Yes"),"Invite 2"))`

This formula will contain 7-8 if statements for specific dates.

My formula is stopping after the first condition if true...even if the second is true as well. I cannot figure out how for it to populate both results if both conditions are true. And then to get it to populate in a concatenated comma-separated value format.

What am I doing wrong? See the sheet below for reference.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You actually have four different cases to address: 1) Both conditions true return "invite 1 and 2" 2) condition 1 is true return "invite 1", 3) condition 2 is true return "invite 2" and 4) either is true return "". With an IF in excel, the second "ELSE" argument won't execute at all if the condition is true, so the order in which you put the conditions matter:

```
=IF(AND(daydiff1 >= 5, daydiff2 > 5), "Invite 1" & "; " & "Invite 2", IF(daydiff1 >= 5, "Invite 1", IF(daydiff2 >= 5, "Invite 2", "")))
```

Ps. I use "daydiff" here just as a placemarker for your actual references.

**Also**, if you want to be fancy, use CHOOSE instead (more efficient since you don't repeat the same comparison operations):

```
=CHOOSE((daydiff1 >= 5)*1 + (daydiff2 >=5)*2 + 1, "", "Invite 1", "Invite 2", "Invite 1 and 2")
```

Or if you have many dates to check and yes conditions:

```
="Invite " & MID(IF(AND(daydiff1 >=5, flag1 <> "yes"), " & 1","") & IF(AND(daydiff2 >=5, flag2 <> "yes"), " & 2","") & IF(AND(daydiff3 >=5, flag3 <> "yes"), " & 3","") & ... & IF(AND(daydiff6 >=5, flag6 <> "yes"), " & 6",""), 4, 50)
```

or

```
=CHOOSE(AND(daydiff1 >= 5, flag1 <> "yes")*2^0 + (daydiff2 >=5, flag2 <> "yes")*2^1 + (daydiff3 >=5, flag3 <> "yes")*2^2 + ... + (daydiff8 >=5, flag8 <> "yes")*2^7 + 1, "", "text1", "text2", "text1,2", "text3", "text1,3", "text2,3", "text1,2,3", "text4", "text1,4", "text2,4", "text3,4", "text1,3,4", "text2,3,4", "text1,2,3,4", ..., "text1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8")
```

The problem with the latter approach is the more tasks you add, the more possible combinations you have. 2 tasks have 2^2=4 text answers to list in CHOOSE. 8 tasks => 2^8 = 256 text answers to list (but CHOOSE has a maximum 254).

I much prefer concatenating individual messages rather than the combinations:

```
=MID(IF(AND(daydiff1 >=5, flag1 <> "yes"), " & text1","") & IF(AND(daydiff2 >=5, flag2 <> "yes"), " & text2","") & IF(AND(daydiff3 >=5, flag3 <> "yes"), " & text3","") & ... & IF(AND(daydiff8 >=5, flag8 <> "yes"), " & text8",""), 4, 1000)
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I do this with having to also check this: `,$Y12<>"Yes:`. This checks to make sure a task is not complete. And, is there a better way to do this? As mentioned in my question, I will have 7 or 8 dates to check.

Comment: Yeah this will still work, just add the add the `<> "YES"` condition in AND(...) functions. As for multiple dates... the choose option will work, but maybe theres a better solution still.

Comment: Thank you. I like the Choose function concept. Is there a way to work in the second <> "YES" part of it? The third option unfortunately won't work because my text won't always be "Invite".

Comment: I updated my answer. Kindly checkmark the answer if it worked for you!

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to follow your "MID" formula. However, whenever I try implementing the formula, Excel adds a " ' " (an apostrophe) before the formula, so I can't tell if it is working or not.

Comment: When you copy and paste the formula, don't just hit paste, but click in the formula bar up top, then press CTRL+V. Alternatively edit the cell and remove the `'`.  Note, as is the formula wouldn't work as you need to substitute the *daydiff* and *flag* placeholders with the correct references in your sheet, and also replace the "..." part with however many more comparisons you need to do.

Comment: That is what I did. I replaced your placeholders. Even if I manually type out the entire formula again, it won't sustain the formula. It adds the apostrophe each time. If I try to remove it, it simply adds it back.

Comment: Maybe first clear the cell, then change the format of the cell to general (it might be that it is currently on text formatting). Lastly check if your localization setting arent interfering. Some languages use ";" instead of "," for separators.

Comment: Thanks! That cell is corrupted. I am trying in a different. I am no longer getting the apostrophe. But I cannot get the formula to work. I have an error in it somewhere to where Excel will not populate it. Do you see it? I cannot figure it out. See update to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting functions, you can just concatenate them:

```
=TRIM( 
  IF(AND($W12-TODAY()>=-5,$Y12<>"Yes"),"Invite 1","") 
  & " " 
  & IF(AND($Z12-TODAY()>=-5,$AB12<>"Yes"),"Invite 2","") 
)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is displaying the text if not finished. However, for some reason the date check isn't working. I am having due dates that are greater than five without "Yes" being selected that still appear.

Comment: I've just copied your IF function. Was your original formula working and the one proposed by me not?

Comment: Yes, I created that, but with just the isolated check, the formula worked. It seems the date part is being overridden with the new forumla.

Comment: As I don't have your data, I can't fix it for you. Please evaluate your formula (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7 ), it can help